# Blogdown download fails

Tags: r, rstudio, cran, blogdown

I have this error when I try to install the `blogdown` package with the RStudio's packages panel. I guess it's something basic, but I don't know what it means!

```
> install.packages("blogdown")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
blogdown    0.6    0.7             FALSE

installing the source package ‘blogdown’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/blogdown_0.7.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/blogdown_0.7.tar.gz': HTTP status was '502 Bad Gateway'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/blogdown_0.7.tar.gz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘blogdown’ failed
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I just waited and retried 5 minutes later and it worked without any modification, but I'm still interested in understanding what this error was!

Comment: There was an issue with the service cran.rstudio.com. See https://status.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the cran mirror service used. 
For cran.rstudio.com, you can follow status of service here : https://status.rstudio.com/

When you have similar error, you can try another mirror for example, changing the repos in RStudio IDE global options or changing the options `repos` in the call `install.packages` or globally. with `options(repos = c(CRAN='<new-url>')`
```